# 2 Mysql queries in 1 variable, help?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$qry1 = "DELETE FROM
    si_topics
WHERE
    topic_id = '". $_GET['topic'] ."'
DELETE FROM 
    si_posts
WHERE
    topic_id = '". $_GET['topic'] ."'";

$mysqlqry1 = mysql_query($qry1);
if($mysqlqry1){
    echo 'Topic deleted from database!';
} else {
    echo 'Mysql query failed!';
}
```

This gives the message `Mysql query failed!`, why?

Greetings

Comment: Please be aware that your code like that is funderable for SQL-Injections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a semicolon between your two delete statements.

Also, multiple queries are not supported in `mysql_query`.

From [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

> mysql_query() sends a unique query **(multiple queries are not supported)** to the currently active database on the server that's associated with the specified link_identifier.`

Answer (score 1):

You can not run multiple queries in [mysql_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) function in once.

Try [mysqli::multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) instead to run multiple queries. queries can be separated by `;`

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the manual (my emphasis)

> mysql_query() sends a unique query (**multiple queries are not supported**)

If you want to execute several SQL statements in a single query, you need to use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and [multi-query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php), and each statement needs to be separated by a semi-colon (;)

Answer (score 1):

Because:

- you're sending one query with invalid syntax, and
- even if you'd added the semicolon between queries (how else is the MySQL server supposed to know where your second query starts?!?), PHP's old library [doesn't support](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) that here.

Use [`mysqli.multi_query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) instead.

You should also either use prepared statements or at the very least sanitise your inputs, as your code has a huge SQL Injection vulnerability (how are people *still* writing PHP like this?!? what are they teaching in these "schools"?! aghh!)

Comment: +1 for "what are they teaching in these "schools"?!"... I gave up asking that question years ago

Answer (score 0):

PHP does not allow running 2 queries in one go.

You need to split your queries in 2 variables and run them one by one.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

The documentation explains:

> mysql_query() sends a unique query
>   (multiple queries are not supported)
>   to the currently active database on
>   the server that's associated with the
>   specified link_identifier.

The standard MySQL separator semicolon ( ; ) will not work here.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to specify multiple delete conditions across several tables, then you can use JOIN syntax for the DELETE statement, however this might be inefficient - but that way, the query will fit within mysql_query();

Someone already mentioned mysqli and multi_query function, thumbs up for that :)

On the other hand, your code is extremely prone to SQL injection attacks, always clean your $_POST and $_GET input before using it in the query directly!

Answer (score -2):

Add mysql_error ($link) after 'echo 'Mysql query failed!';' line

That will explain the problem.

Comment: This is not an answer, should be a comment instead.